# How to display table in J-frame by button

Tags: java, button, display

I solved the logic puzzle by implementing various logical constraints. I've modeled this puzzle: https://github.com/.../.../java/org/jacop/examples/fd/Zebra.java
Everything works. The result appears to me in the console, just like the rest of the parameters (Nodes, Decisions, WrongDecisions, etc.).
The result is as an array, and the parameters as a simple display of the function (eg System.out.print (search.getNodes () + "\ t");).
The problem is that I do not know how to display all of this in the text field of my JFrame using the button I created.

All I know is that in order to do this, I need to set a function in the button to display results in a loop (sorted by type) from this table with results, and in addition to display parameters and a simple text box with the answer to the riddle question.

```
//this is part of the code from ClpCombinatorics.java that is in core catalog.


...



 IntVar color[] = new IntVar[5];
        IntVar nationality[] = new IntVar[5];
        IntVar port[] = new IntVar[5];
        IntVar carries[] = new IntVar[5];
        IntVar leaves[] = new IntVar[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            color[i] = new IntVar(store, colorChimney[i], 1, 5);
            port[i] = new IntVar(store, portNames[i], 1, 5);
            carries[i] = new IntVar(store, carriesNames[i], 1, 5);
            nationality[i] = new IntVar(store, nationalityNames[i], 1, 5);
            leaves[i] = new IntVar(store, leavesHours[i], 1, 5);
            vars.add(color[i]);
            vars.add(nationality[i]);
            vars.add(port[i]);
            vars.add(carries[i]);
            vars.add(leaves[i]);
        }

        store.impose(new Alldifferent(color));
        store.impose(new Alldifferent(port));
        store.impose(new Alldifferent(carries));
        store.impose(new Alldifferent(nationality));
        store.impose(new Alldifferent(leaves));

        //S1
        store.impose(new XeqY(nationality[igreek], leaves[isix]));
        store.impose(new XeqY(nationality[igreek], carries[icoffe]));


...


public boolean searchMostConstrainedStatic() {

        Search<IntVar> search = new DepthFirstSearch<IntVar>();

        SelectChoicePoint<IntVar> select =
            new SimpleSelect<>(vars.toArray(new IntVar[1]), new MostConstrainedStatic<>(), new IndomainMin<>());

        boolean result2 = search.labeling(store, select);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(search.getNodes() + "\t");
        System.out.print(search.getDecisions() + "\t");
        System.out.print(search.getWrongDecisions() + "\t");
        System.out.print(search.getBacktracks() + "\t");
        System.out.print(search.getMaximumDepth() + "\t");

        if (!result2)
            System.out.println("**** No Solution ****");

        return result2;


    }

    private SelectChoicePoint<IntVar> solution;

    //@Override
    public SelectChoicePoint<IntVar> getSolution(){
        return solution;
    }
```

It's working - solving the riddle, but i don't know how to display it by clicking the button named "SOLVE" next to my J-frame, as i mentioned before.

Comment: You will have to look at some Swing tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: Thank you very much for Your help Sascha!